# transfer interfaces from delphi dll to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, delphi, com

I have a Delphi written DLL that exposes some interfaces to a vb.net application.
The interfaces inherit from IUnknown (but this could be changed if required), simplified example:

```
  IWindow = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{E9A11D0B-8A05-4CBA-83FA-C5CC6818DF6E}']
    function GetCaption(var Caption: PChar): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
```

Same interface in vb.net application:

```
<ComImport(), Guid("E9A11D0B-8A05-4CBA-83FA-C5CC6818DF6E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IWindow
    ReadOnly Property Caption() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> String
End Interface
```

This all works ok.

Now I want to transfer a collection of IWindow to vb.net, and in the vb.net application I want to be able to loop through it with a for in loop.

I read that it's possible using IEnumerable/IEnumerator but I don't quite understand how to implement them. Are there any good tutorials about this, specifically showing the declarations on both side? Example code would be great.

Please note that I prefer not create a com dll that should be registered and imported. Currently I export a function that enabled me to obtain an interface.

Comment: are you sure about var Caption: PChar? That looks like you allocate memory in Delphi but free it over in the .net code. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: It's a PChar to an array of char in the implementing class, so the memory is valid as long as the interface has a refcount > 0. I am using interfaces so that I don't have to worry about allocation and deallocation.

Comment: For what it's worth I'd do this with a COM BStr which is super easy. It's WideString on the Delphi side and UnmanagedType.BStr on the .net side. It's allocated using the COM allocator. I know that's not the question but there you go all the same.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I opted for it because of specific performance reasons. I really appreciate the "thinking along" though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution working, but I am not entirely happy with it. I am placing it here as an answer, hopefully comments of other people may improve it or (even better) a better answer will be placed.

I found that the Delphi's declaration (Delphi 2010) of IEnumerator and IEnumerable are not using the stdcall calling convention so I declared them like this:

```
  IEnumerator = interface(IInterface)
  ['{496B0ABE-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}']
    function MoveNext: Boolean; safecall;
    function GetCurrent: IWindow; safecall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  IEnumerable = interface(IInterface)
  ['{496B0ABE-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}']
    function GetEnumerator(var Enumerator: IEnumerator): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
```

My collection interface inherits from IEnumerable (but has it's own GUID):

```
  IWindows = interface(IEnumerable)
  ['{D9174D5A-4946-4E5A-95B1-2CD521C3BF73}']
  end;
```

The class implements IEnumerable, IEnumerator and IEnumVariant. <s>I think that I can remove IEnumerator but I need to do more testing before I can confirm.</s>

```
  TIWindows = class(TInterfacedObject, IWindows, IEnumerable, IEnumVariant)
```

On the VB.NET side it looks like this:

```
<ComImport(), Guid("D9174D5A-4946-4E5A-95B1-2CD521C3BF73"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IWindows
    Inherits IEnumerable
    Shadows Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator
End Interface
```

I had to override GetEnumerator because if I don't I get a null reference exception and on the Delphi side GetEnumerator() is never called (VMT offset problem?).

The calling code:

```
Dim Windows As IWindows
Dim Window As IWindow
Try
    Windows = Session.TopLevelWindows
    For Each Window In Windows
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Window.Caption
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Handle Exception
End Try
```

The Dim Windows as IWindow is required to make it work, without it I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I tried to use generic in vb.net side:

Shadows Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of IDNKWindow)

But it gives the error: Cannot marshal 'return value': Generic types cannot be marshaled.

Comment: Why don't you try returning a safearray of IUnknown from Delphi instead? I think it should be easier, and you can probably marshal it as an array of objects on vb.net side.

Comment: What's the advantage of returning a safearray? Can it be walked through using a for each loop in vb.net?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. It might be a bit troublesome on the Delphi side to produce the safearray, but it will be very easy to use on vb.net, just as any other array of objects.