# 3rd Party Delphi DLL Consumption

Tags: xml, delphi, dll, pinvoke, system-center

I have exhausted my googling options...

We are using System Centre Orchestrator to automate user creation in multiple systems. We have a third party point of sale application that stores user passwords in the DB in an encrypted format that their application can read. For our automated inserts into the user DB we need to be able to insert an encrypted password for the application to recognise.

They wouldn't provide us with the encryption methodology they followed, but have created a DLL for us to consume written in Delphi. It takes a string passed in an XML wrapper, then returns an XML response with the encrypted password string.

From a System Centre Orchestrator point of view, what would be the best way to consume this DLL, bearing in mind myself or or Systems Engineer who is implementing this have never done something like this before.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

A string will be passed to the executable containing XML in the following format

```
<passwordEncryptionRequest>
<passwordIn>?</passwordIn>
<connectionDetails>
<serverName>?</serverName>
<serverInstance>?</serverInstance>
<userName>?</userName>
<connectionPassword>?</connectionPassword>
</connectionDetails>
</passwordEncryptionRequest>
```

A string will be returned from the executable containing XML in the following format

```
<passwordEncryptionResponse> 
<passwordOut>?</passwordOut>
<passwordEncryptionErrorResponse>
<errorDescription>?</errorDescription>
</passwordEncryptionErrorResponse>
</passwordEncryptionResponse>
```

The vendor came back to me and with some example code.

The function declaration is (Delphi):

```pascal
function EncryptPassword(inputString: PWideChar; var outputString: PWideChar): wordbool; export; stdCall;
```

Example to use (c#):

```
[DllImport("PasswordEncrypt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool EncryptPassword(string inputString, ref string outputString);

public FormTestEncryption()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string outputString = string.Empty;
    string inputString = string.Format(
         "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
         "<passwordEncryptionRequest>" +
             "<passwordIn>{0}</passwordIn>" +
             "<connectionDetails>" +
                 "<serverName>{1}</serverName>" +
                 "<serverInstance>{2}</serverInstance>" +
                 "<userName>{3}</userName>" +
                 "<connectionPassword>{4}</connectionPassword>" +
             "</connectionDetails>" +
         "</passwordEncryptionRequest>", 
    textPassword.Text, textServer.Text, textInstance.Text, textDBUser.Text, textDBPassword.Text);

    textOutput.Clear();

    bool result = EncryptPassword(inputString, ref outputString);

    textOutput.Text = outputString;
}
```

EDIT 2: After implementing the suggested definition and call i do in fact get a return string, however only when i enabled native code debugging and continued through the two break points. Stack trace was;

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@8() Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpReportHeapFailure@4()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12() Unknown
ole32.dll!76f96e6a()    Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ole32.dll] 
[External Code] 
WindowsFormsApplication2.exe!WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 52    C#
[External Code] 
WindowsFormsApplication2.exe!WindowsFormsApplication2.Program.Main() Line 20    C#
[External Code]
```

Seeing as it IS now actually implementing the 3rd party dll correctly (i checked the returned string and was fine), i have marked this as answered. I will try muscle my way through these other issues now :)

Thank you all for your input, i appreciate the help.

Regards, Dan

Comment: You've provided no information about the DLL they provided you, the XML wrapper, or the XML response it returns. How are we to be expected to help? What is the published API for calling the DLL they provided? (The function definition, typically in C, for the DLL. It's often provided in a C header file (something.h), but it must at least be in the documentation.) Please post the function definitions from that header file, or a text quote from the documentation they provided. Otherwise, there's not enough information here to help you, and you'll likely be referred to the vendor support.

Comment: Hi Ken. The XML parameters as per the functional specification they provided are as follows;

A string will be passed to the executable containing XML in the following format:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<passwordEncryptionRequest>
<passwordIn>?</passwordIn>
<connectionDetails>
<serverName>?</serverName>
<serverInstance>?</serverInstance>
<userName>?</userName>
<connectionPassword>?</connectionPassword>
</connectionDetails>
</passwordEncryptionRequest>

Comment: A string will be returned from the executable containing XML in the following format.
<passwordEncryptionResponse>
<passwordOut>?</passwordOut>
<passwordEncryptionErrorResponse>
<errorDescription>?</errorDescription>
</passwordEncryptionErrorResponse>
</passwordEncryptionResponse>

Comment: I am reading through the rest of the doc, but it is pretty barebones and doesnt provide any information regarding API

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide that information there, where it can be properly formatted and it's readily available. It's difficult to wade through all that clutter in comment form to make sense of it. Thanks.

Comment: If they wrote the DLL to actually take a Delphi `String` as input and return a Delphi `String` as output, then it will only work in the particular version of Delphi that the DLL was written in, and even then it is not likely to work correctly due to issues with memory management across the DLL boundary.  On the other hand, if they were smart enough *NOT* to use the Delphi `String` type, then they likely used `PAnsiChar`/`PWideChar` instead, which they should have, then you stand a chance.  But either way, you do need to know the actual declaration of the exported function in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have emailed them requesting this information. 

What would have been easier for me is if they let me know their hashing method so i could create a stored procedure on our DB to convert it :( *sigh*. I'm a noobie sorry

Comment: I have edited the post to contain the XML and reply from the vendor. Looks like they provided an example. I was thinking of doing similar with VB which I am marginally more familar with (I'm mainly an ABAP developer). Remy looks like you were right with PWideChar :)

Comment: Very odd implementation. Should have been called something like  `ProcessXml( Request, out Response )` or `XmlApi( Request, out Response )` or `EncryptPassword( Password, ConnServerName, ConnServerInstance, ConnUserName, ConnPassword, out EncryptedPassword )`

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758479/transfer-interfaces-from-delphi-dll-to-vb-net is worth reading -> they should use an interface and `WideString`

Comment: And at least: why do **you** want to insert the password into DB? Their application knows how to read and write, so the DLL should take all needed data and store the user credentials.

Comment: The declaration they provided is flawed. It expects you to provide a variable that has no memory allocated, which they will return populated with memory not allocated by your application. Where does that resulting memory get released? Is there a corresponding function in the DLL that you call afterwards to do so? If not, you've got a huge memory leak in your app, because the DLL runs in your process space; every call to the DLL will leak the size of the return buffer, and if the DLL is called frequently that can be a pretty significant leak. The XML side if things is trivial.

Comment: We don't [b]need[/b] to insert the password ourselves, we have the standard user creation provided by the POS software. However we have many systems we want to set up a user in one fell swoop automatically. Our SAP systems are easy. Saves a lot of manual work for us in the long run.

Comment: I will look for some reading material for memory allocation. I am also inexperienced with that... I also need to talk to them about logging, as at the moment even when implementing as they recommend the program hangs and then quits with an uninformative error.  I need to hit the sack but will provide some more info tomorrow in my main post. Thanks for the time guys. Really appreciated!

Comment: @Dan You get me wrong. If I had to add a user to a system, then I don't want to ask the system for a structure/data and add this data to the system datastore. I just want to pass to the system the desired username, password and just want to get informed, that the system has done this. I do not need to know how and where that information is stored. I only need to know the API-call and they can change the system without telling me aslong they did not change the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that these developers have supplied cannot be called reliably. And it certainly cannot be called from C# using the code you have been supplied. The function you have been supplied has been declared like this:

```
function EncryptPassword(inputString: PWideChar; 
  var outputString: PWideChar): WordBool; stdcall;
```

The return value really should be `LongBool`, but that won't actually matter.

The main problem is the second parameter. This requires the Delphi code to allocate a string, and return the pointer to that string in `outputString`. The calling code has no way to deallocate that string. C# code that could call the function looks like this:

```
[DllImport("PasswordEncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool EncryptPassword(string inputString, 
    out IntPtr outputString);
```

You would call it like this:

```
IntPtr outputStringPtr;
if (!EncryptPassword(inputString, out outputStringPtr))
    // handle error
string outputString = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(outputStringPtr);
```

And this leaves the memory that `outputStringPtr` still allocated with no way for you to deallocate it.

Of course, even this assumes that the Delphi developer allocated the memory in such a way that it would outlast the call to `EncryptPassword`. Quite possibly they implemented `EncryptPassword` like this:

```
function EncryptPassword(inputString: PWideChar; 
  var outputString: PWideChar): WordBool; stdcall;
var
  output: UnicodeString;
begin
  output := InternalEncryptPassword(string(intputString));
  outputString := PWideChar(output);
  Result := True;
end;
```

This function deallocates the memory that `outputString` points to as soon as it returns.

So, the bottom line is that the code you have been supplied with is no good. Here is what it should look like:

```
function EncryptPassword(inputString: WideString; 
  out outputString: WideString): LongBool; stdcall;
```

That function might be implemented something like this:

```
function EncryptPassword(inputString: WideString; 
  out outputString: WideString): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
  outputString := InternalEncryptPassword(intputString);
  Result := True;
end;
```

On the C# side it looks like this:

```
[DllImport("PasswordEncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool EncryptPassword(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    string inputString, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    out string outputString
);
```

And call it like this:

```
string outputString;
if (!EncryptPassword(inputString, out outputString))
    // handle error
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply David. I will implement as you suggest and see how it goes! Might not be till this afternoon in my timezone but i will give feedback as soon as possible. Cheers!

Comment: But do remember that my answer states that quite likely you need the other devs to fix their Delphi code.

Comment: The implementation worked mostly. When i run in debug mode i do get my output string as desired. However during normal execution i get an application crash (stackhash). I would say it was DEP causing it but I temporarily disabled it and still got the error.

Comment: I believe that the Delphi DLL is fundamentally broken. I don't believe anything you can do can fix it. You need to get back to the original devs. Show them my answer here.

Answer (score -1):

declare function like

```
    function EncryptPassword(inputString: PWideChar; var outputString: PWideChar)
: wordbool; stdcall; external 'PasswordEncrypt.dll';
```

build a

```
inputstring := '<passwordEncryptionRequest>
<passwordIn>?</passwordIn>
<connectionDetails>
<serverName>?</serverName>
<serverInstance>?</serverInstance>
<userName>?</userName>
<connectionPassword>?</connectionPassword>
</connectionDetails>
</passwordEncryptionRequest>'
```

with passwordIn,serverName,userName datas

call the function

```
EncryptPassword(inputString,outputString);
```

if the function return true you will get a xml string in outputString parse it and find your password in  tag

Comment: The asker is trying to consume a Delphi DLL using C#. Even in Delphi the code above likely fails.